# Connecting Logitech DiNovo Mini to Windows 10 via generic bluetooth

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I have a Logitech DiNovo Mini keyboard that I am trying to connect with a regular bluetooth receiver.

I have four of these keyboards, I am trying to connect them to a Windows 10 PC via a generic bluetooth receiver. It asks for a long code to be typed with the DiNovo Mini but only for a couple of times until it starts asking for a PIN code instead. I only got one of these four keyboards to connect, presumably I typed the long code wrong or too slowly. How do I make Windows ask for the long code again instead of the PIN? Logitech says this product "does not have the capability to ask for a PIN code", suggesting a problem with Windows 10. Still, 0000, 1111 and 1234 were tried without success. It also appears in Steam Deck's bluetooth devices too, but simply refuses to connect without asking anything.

Answer (score -1):

I lost the bluetooth dongle of my dinovo mini. I solved the pin trouble following the instructions give here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkt8N8R0fP8

Now I can connect my dinovo mini with my windows 10 laptop.

hope it helps.

Comment: This is not an answer - this is a link. Once the link dies, your post will become useless.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1167247)

Comment: Basically, the video says:  
1 Control Panel  
2 Add device  
3 Obviously turn the keyboard discovery (it has a button next to the battery)  
4 Select when the Add Device wizard shows the keyboard  (diNovo)  
5 Click on "Try enter a code"   
6 A code will appear. Input it in the keyboard and press ENTER there  

That will do